# ANT: Build Failed: failed to create task or type testng:

Tags: selenium, ant, build

```
<project name="name" default="test" basedir=".">

   <!-- Define <testng> task -->

<taskdef resource="testngtasks"> 
      <classpath>
         <pathelement location="/lib/testng-6.8.5.jar"/>
      </classpath>
 </taskdef>

   <property name="testdir" location="test" />
   <property name="srcdir" location="src" />
   <property name="libdir" location="lib" />
   <property name="full-compile" value="true" />

   <path id="classpath.base"/>
   <path id="classpath.test">

   <fileset dir="${libdir}">
      <include name="**/*.jar" />
   </fileset>

   <pathelement location="${testdir}" />
   <pathelement location="${srcdir}" />

   <path refid="classpath.base" />
   </path>

   <target name="clean" >
      <delete verbose="${full-compile}">
         <fileset dir="${testdir}" includes="**/*.class" />
      </delete>
    <echo>Cleaned Successfully.</echo>
   </target>

   <target name="compile" depends="clean">
      <javac srcdir="${srcdir}" destdir="${testdir}" verbose="${full-compile}">
         <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
      </javac>
    <echo>Java file compiled Successfully.</echo>
   </target>

   <target name="test" depends="compile">
      <testng outputdir="${testdir}" classpath="classpath.test"> 
         <xmlfileset dir="${srcdir}" includes="TestNG.xml"/> 
      </testng>
   </target>

</project>
```

Following error is being received: 
BUILD FAILED 
Problem: failed to create task or type testng 
Cause: The name is undefined. 
Action: Check the spelling. 
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared. 
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

It worked but now I am receiving another error:

```
test:    [testng] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterExcept
    ion
       [testng]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
       [testng]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
       [testng]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
       [testng]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
       [testng]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
       [testng]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
       [testng] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.Pa
    rameterException
       [testng]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
       [testng]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
       [testng]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       [testng]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
       [testng]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       [testng]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       [testng]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       [testng]     ... 6 more
       [testng] The tests failed.

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
    Total time: 3 seconds
```

Following is output of classpath.test,prop:

```
<path>\lib\apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;
<path>\lib\bsh-1.3.0.jar;
<path>\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;
<path>\commons-codec-1.9.jar;
<path>\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;
<path>\commons-exec-1.1.jar;
<path>\commons-io-2.4.jar;
<path>\commons-jxpath-1.3.jar;
<path>\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;
<path>\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;
<path>\cssparser-0.9.14.jar;
<path>\gson-2.3.1.jar;
<path>\guava-18.0.jar;
<path>\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;
<path>\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;
<path>\lib\htmlunit-2.15.jar;
<path>\lib\htmlunit-core-js-2.15.jar;
<path>\lib\httpclient-4.3.6.jar;
<path>\lib\httpcore-4.3.3.jar;
<path>\lib\httpmime-4.3.6.jar;
<path>\lib\ini4j-0.5.2.jar;
<path>\lib\jcommander-1.29.jar;
<path>\lib\jetty-websocket-8.1.8.jar;
<path>\lib\jna-3.4.0.jar;
<path>\lib\jna-platform-3.4.0.jar;
<path>\lib\junit-dep-4.11.jar;
<path>\lib\nekohtml-1.9.21.jar;
<path>\lib\netty-3.5.7.Final.jar;
<path>\lib\operadriver-1.5.jar;
<path>\lib\phantomjsdriver-1.2.1.jar;
<path>\lib\protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar;
<path>\lib\sac-1.3.jar;
<path>\lib\selenium-java-2.45.0-srcs.jar;
<path>\lib\selenium-java-2.45.0.jar;
<path>\lib\serializer-2.7.1.jar;
<path>\lib\testng-6.8.5.jar;
<path>\lib\xalan-2.7.1.jar;
<path>\lib\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar;
<path>\lib\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it cannot find a jar.

Try

```
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="/full/path/to/testng.jar"> 
</taskdef>
```

Or put testng.jar in ANT_HOME/lib and use:

```
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="testng.jar"> 
</taskdef>
```

You should add jars to your `classpath.test`

```
 <path id="classpath.test">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>  
  </path>
```

Where the class `com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException` is defined?

You can print classpath to ensure the jar is included in it.

```
<pathconvert property="classpath.test.prop" refid="classpath.test"/>
<echo>Classpath is ${classpath.test.prop}</echo>
```

you should use `classpathref` not `classpath` in your testng task call

```
<testng outputdir="${testdir}" classpathref="classpath.test"> 
         <xmlfileset dir="${srcdir}" includes="TestNG.xml"/> 
</testng>
```

Comment: It worked. But I am receiving another error. I hae updated the post with error.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you upvote and accept useful answers people will more willingly help you.

Comment: It is already added:path id="classpath.test">

   <fileset dir="${libdir}">
      <include name="**/*.jar" />
   </fileset>

   <pathelement location="${testdir}" />
   <pathelement location="${srcdir}" />

   <path refid="classpath.base" />
   </path>

Comment: It shows all the jar files. An I am still receiving the error. I have updated the post.

Comment: I downlaoded latest jcommander from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander/1.48 but it is still not working.

Comment: It helped. My problem is solved. I am able to run using ant. Many thanks.